# if statement in opening a file indention

Tags: python, python-3.x, txt

Dear community I have a problem that although it's seems to be not a big deal, it took away sleep from me.
and I don't need sleep, I NEED answer!

I want to open a file, and if the string "MODIFIED" was in the file's content, I want to print('already modified'), then printing the content of the file
here is my code:

```
with open(f"contents\\docs.txt", "r") as f:
    if "MODIFIED" in f.readlines():
        print("already modified")
    
    print(f.readlines())
    print()
```

it's seems to be ok, but the weird part is, the file does not contain the string "MODIFIED", so it's just have to normally print the content of the file, but is only return a empty list [] !
(The file is not empty!)
and if I run it without the if statement, it will normally return the content as it should.

```
with open(f"contents\\docs.txt", "r") as f:
    #if "MODIFIED" in f.readlines():
        #print("already modified")
    
    print(f.readlines())
    print()
```

I just don't get it, what does a if statement do to the code that the code return empty list.

- the doc.txt file that I want to return it's content

```
before the flood
david attenborough: a life on our planet
an inconvenient truth
home 2009
kiss the ground 2020
seaspiracy 2020
cosmos
```

it's the first time I'm encountering this, idk what to call it, bug?
I would appreciate if you guys help me find out what's going wrong

Comment: `"MODIFIED" in f.readlines()` will return False everytime since "MODIFIED" is a string compared against a list. Do `"MODIFIED" in f.read()`.

Comment: The condition will never be true because `readlines()` keeps the newlines at the end of each line. You need to strip those off first. Then it will match a line that contains only `MODIFIED`.

Comment: Where is `MODIFIED` in your sample file?

Comment: @Barmar even if that's the case he's using `in` and not `=`

Comment: @thethiny What's wrong with that? `string in list_of_strings` is fine.

Comment: @Barmar as discussed in the current top-voted answer, we're pending OP's response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you read from a file, it saves where you left off. `readlines` reads the whole file, so when you call `readlines` again, there is nothing left to read. Store it in a variable:

```py
with open(f"contents\\docs.txt", "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    if "MODIFIED" in lines:
        print("already modified")
    print(lines)
```

Note: this still won't work unless you strip off the trailing `'\n'`s at the end of each line. An alternative is to join `lines` by a `\n` so you get a string not a list.

```py
with open(f"contents\\docs.txt", "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    if "MODIFIED" in '\n'.join(lines):
        print("already modified")
    print(lines)
```

However, this is not good practice, so this is another alternative:

```py
with open(f"contents\\docs.txt", "r") as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()
    if "MODIFIED" in lines:
        print("already modified")
    print(lines)
```

`splitlines` does not have the trailing `\n`.

Comment: `if "MODIFIED" in lines:` will never be `True` though.

Comment: @Axe319 - added alternative to fix that problem.

Comment: @TheThonnu, that's a very silly alternative. Why read line-by-line and then join them into a string instead of just reading the data as a big string (and not using `readlines` at all) in the first place? Doing the work to split them only to join them back together... what's the point?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - I know, but it still works, with minimal change to the OPs original code.

Comment: Sure, but if we're a teaching resource, we should be showcasing best practices rather than preserving peoples' mistakes, unless we know they made that mistake deliberately / for a purpose.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - added another alternative.

Comment: This answer does not solve OPs question. `"MODIFIED" in lines` is always false regardless of the trailing `\n` since `in` compares `in` and not `=`.

Comment: @thethiny - I don't get what you mean. I've tested it and it works. What do you mean by '*`"MODIFIED" in lines` is always false*'? It's not.

Comment: @TheThonnu What did you test it against? `if "MODIFIED" in ["line1", "line2", "line3", "MODIFIED"]` would work but OP asked if the string is in the file, not a line on its own.

Comment: @thethiny - we don't know that. [Barmar asked OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73625360/if-statement-in-opening-a-file-indention/73625396?noredirect=1#comment130013922_73625360) where "MODIFIED" was in the file, but OP didn't respond. And even if it's not on it's own in a line, my first alternative solution handles that.

Comment: @TheThonnu Alright then in that case I cannot disagree with you. I have provided an alternative solution on my own that handles both of these cases but still approved your solution.

Comment: Thanks guys! all of you helped me, I have read all the comments and learned lot, now I can finally shut my eyes.

Comment: and because you asked, "MODIFIED" is on a newline (first or last line).but it doesn't matter now because I have already got my answer, thanks to you guys.

Answer (score 0):

`"MODIFIED" in f.readlines()` will always evaluate to `False` since `"MODIFIED"` is a `string` while `f.readlines()` is a `list` of `str`. Therefore it will compare `"MODIFIED"` with every element of that `list`.
As stated by [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73625396/1961688) `readlines` would also add the trailing `\n` for each line, so even if your file contains `MODIFIED` it would actually be read as `MODIFIED\n`, which makes the evaluation come to `False`. However as pointed out in the comments by Aran-Fey the evaluation can become `True` if `MODIFIED` was the last line in the file and there was no `newline` at the end.

A trailing `\n` would not affect your comparison if you were comparing a string against another as `in` checks for `in` and not for equality, which is what `=` does. Therefore `"MODIFIED"` in `"IAMAMODIFIEDSTRING"` is `True`.

The right thing to do would be to replace it with `in f.read()` which makes the solution as follows:

```
with open(f"contents\\docs.txt", "r") as f:
    data = f.read()
    if "MODIFIED" in data:
        print("already modified")
    
    print(data)
    print()
```

However, if you want to make sure `MODIFIED` is on a line on its own then you would do:

```
with open(f"contents\\docs.txt", "r") as f:
    data = f.readlines()
    if "MODIFIED" in [line.strip() for line in data]:
        print("already modified")
    
    print('\n'.join(data))
    print()
```

Comment: `"MODIFIED" in lines` can actually return True if it's the last line and the file doesn't end with a newline.

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying. `string in list` works if the elements of the list are strings. E.g. `"abc" in ["foo", "abc", "bar"]`

Comment: Thanks guys! all of you helped me, I have read all the comments and learned lot, now I can finally shut my eyes.

Comment: @Aran-Fey I actually missed that. Thanks for notifying me.

Comment: @Barmar I was editing the question when you posted your comment by adding an explanation.